# How to create a new SP connection in PingFederate?

Tags: single-sign-on, pingfederate, zendesk

We are using PingFederate to enable SSO. It's being mapped with the LDAP directory server and our site is able to use SSO.  Now we are integrating a helpdesk software application which is being hosted somewhere within our own site.  We want the help desk user to be able to login using our site credentials.  For that I need to add the help desk as a partner (SP) in PingFederate acting as an IdP.

How can I achieve this? A brief explanation would be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of good information in our documentation on managing SP connections: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide%2FmanagingSpConnections.html

How the connection is made largely depends on how you authenticate users, what attributes you're sending, and what the SAML capabilities/details are of your help desk software.  If no SAML features are available, you may have to use one of our [Integrations](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/marketplace-integration-home-page) to either front end it (with a web server plugin, like Apache or IIS) or modify the app (using one of our language kits or agentless integration approach).

You may also want to consider sitting in one of our training sessions on PingFederate basics: https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources/training.html

Should all else fail, our support centre is there to help if you have a valid contract.

Comment: Hey Scott. Thanks a lot for your information. I was there on 4th OCt, in the training room, when John Phan from pingfedertae was giving lecturer on Creating connections. Can i have a link to the recorded video of that session?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the Getting Started - Part 3 recording from our website. It demonstrates how the setup a connection to a typical service provider.

https://www.pingidentity.com/support/training-center/index.cfm/103-creating-a-connection?id=1011570451001

In a nutshell, you would need communicate with your partner about federation and share some information like:
Federation Standard/Protocol,
Base URL, Entity ID, Endpoints,
Binding,
SSO profile,
Attributes,
and so on.

All of the above depends on what federation server your partner is using. Once you have all the information you can quickly setup the connection to your partner within PingFederate.
I hope this helps. I've also sent you a PM.